# Sending GCM push in Node

Tags: android, node.js, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I've got problem with sending message to Google Cloud Messaging by Node application. I've created API key (both server and browser), I've whitelisted in server key server IP and by code

```
        var headers = [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: key=' + apiKey
        ];

        curl("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send", {
            HTTPHEADER: headers,
            POST: true,
            POSTFIELDS: JSON.stringify({
                data: {
                    type: 'xxx',
                    city: 'xxx',
                    url: 'xxx'
                },
                registration_ids: [phoneId]
            })
        }, function () {
            console.log(arguments);
        });
```

I am trying to send simple notification to Android device. Unfortunately, I get **401 Unauthorized** error. I am using `node-curl` library, earlier I tried `node-gcm` and `node-gcm-service` - both with same result. Is there any possibility that I've missed?

Thanks in advance for help,
Dawid.

Answer (score 2):

When sending push notification with node js we can use following code

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm'),
    gcm_message = new gcm.Message(),
    sender = new gcm.Sender(GCM_API_KEY),
    RETRY_COUNT = 4;

gcm_message.addDataWithKeyValue('key1', message);
gcm_message.delayWhileIdle = true;

sender.send(gcm_message, registrationIds, RETRY_COUNT, function(err, result) {
    callback(err, result);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using a incorrect API Key and that is the reason why you is failing. You have to take the API SERVER KEY, of your Google Cloud Console.

Comment: It's old question & already solved; I've enabled few google services, but I've forgotten about one (don't remember which), API key was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of concatenation operator in php for appending values to keys

```
'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey
```

Comment: It was NodeJS so plus was good. In this question it was just a time to wait to get GCM working, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. "Error 401" occurred because I forgot to enable the API - Google Cloud Messaging for Android in [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). After enabling it worked. Hope it helps you.